# Why message is not being added to flashMessanger?

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I created pagination and wanted to add check if user want to access page, which is not exisits. For example, there are 10 pages and user wants to open 999 page. I wanted to add error message, which will show, that there are no 999 page.

I tried this (and this worked):

```
public function listAction() {
    $page = // getting page

    $pagginator = // setting paginator

    // this part will add message to the flashMessanger
    if($page > $paginator->count()) {
        $message = 'There are no such page';
        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($message);
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/news');
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'news' => $paginator,
    ));
}
```

This is working code. This is code for `list` action. This action is executed, when I type in browser this: `example.com/admin/news`. If I will type `example.com/admin/news/page-500` browser will be redirected to `example.com/admin/news` and there will be message `There are no such page`.

I wanted to add same in other parts of my site and I got problem in `index` action of same controller. This is `index` action:

```
public function indexAction() {
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'news' => $this->getItems(),
        'categoryName' => null,
    ));
}
```

As you see, I call function `getItems()`. Code of this function:

```
private function getItems($categoryId = null) {
    $page = // getting page

    $paginator = // getting paginator

    if($page > $paginator->count()) {
        $message = 'There are no such page';
        $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($message);
        if($categoryId) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('news/category', array('category' => $categoryId));
        } else {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('news');
        }
    }

    return $paginator;
}
```

I tried this and I got this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response::count() in
>   F:\Server\domains\zf2-skeleton\module\News\view\news\news\index.phtml
>   on line 32

I realized, that it is because I returning `$this->redirect` as result of `getItems()` function and it is assigned to view variable `news`.

I tried this then:

```
if($page > $paginator->count()) {
    $message = 'There are no such page';
    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($message);
    if($categoryId) {
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('news/category', array('category' => $categoryId));
    } else {
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('news');
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors, but I am not getting message, that page is bad too.

I think... I bet, nobody here doesn't want to know what I think :)

Help me with this problem, please.

How to make redirect + write message to flashMessanger (so I can output it later) correctly in my case?

### Update

I understand, that it is possible to return array from function get items and handle it. One of element will show should zf2 do redirect or not, another will show category id, third will containt paginator by itself, but it is dirty solution (but possible :( ).

Comment: Any luck with $paginator->normalizePageNumber ?

Comment: Well it is same as setCurrentPageNumber, right? I wanted to show error message if page is wrong.

Comment: it's suppose to "Brings the page number in range of the paginator." It does however not call getPageRange so idk. I just tought the cleanest way of doing this is to get to the maximum page and add a flashmessage without a redirect.

Comment: You suggest to use it... So if I will enter page 599,when I have only 10, page will be set to 10 and message will be shown, right?

Comment: yes thats how I would go about it. It depends on how you look at it though. For me personaly the paginator is represented like a container. Within this container I just assume I have "shelfs". Now someone "in our case the url" tells us to get items out of shelf 10 in our container. Our container on the other hand only has 9 shelfs though. I could either go back and tell the the one who asked for the items of shelf 10 there are non. Or I could just assume the caller wanted to play a trick on me or miscalculated in which case I  dont return empty handed but still notice the caller and im done.